# Is IxEdit worth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, editor

I am  intrigued by [IxEdit](http://www.ixedit.com/) and its full-javascript approach that should allow to build nice web pages powered by JQuery effects.

I like also the opportunity to use it on many platforms.

But, is it worth a try ?

Is it complete ? Has it compatibility issues ? Are there better alternative tools ?

Comment: I would like to try IxEdit and I done everything described in ixedit.com/userguide/#startusingixedit (Placing and loading the required files) but couldn't yet boot ixedit... Is it enough to include that code in html page (in head element) and at next load of page, ixedit would appear???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't rely on WYSIWYG editors--My guess is that this editor screws up performance like Frontpage, Dreamweaver -and the likes screws up HTML.

jQuery is pretty simple to understand, once you get hold of the concept of anonymous functions.. And with Stack Overflow at hand, you should be able to get where you want to go in no time.

Also: jQuery is the framework with the largest community and the framework with the largest plugin repository--need a gallery-thingie? No biggie, just browse the [tons of plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/) and find one that fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as JQuery isn't THAT complicated, I wouldn't pay for tools like that.
They also don't support any plugins I guess.

But it's free, so just try it...

Answer (score 1):

I've just d/l IxEdit and am actually kind of excited about it.

It seems you do have to be careful about starting with a blank slate: I tried applying it to an existing page with a few jQ plugins and and it broke.

As for the WYSIWYG aspect of it, I think it would be great for beginners, as it generates the code on the fly, and you have to copy and paste the code into the page. This can give a noob the opportunity to see the code that's made and make sense of how it works.

My two cents.

Comment: I like Adam's view on IxEdit as a learning tool, by looking at the generated code. But you also have to beautify the generated code to understand it, there are many JavaScript beautifiers online.